# Selenium window taking existing cookies and directly logging into application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am trying to automate login to my project application which has login enabled through SSO. In my existing chrome window which I am using to inspect the webelements, I have logged into the application with my credentials.

With the same credentials I am trying to automate the login process. However, when I run my script after initializing the Chrome Driver, my Selenium window is directly opening the home page i.e. the page which loads after users successfully logs in to the application. The login window is not coming. On doing driver.get(applicationURL), the application is directly navigating to the landing page and not the login page.

I am assuming it is using the existing cookies/cache to login. However, my understanding is Selenium initiated windows are without any existing cookies or cache.

When I try running the same script on Chrome icognito mode, then the login window is opening.

This is my browser initialization code -

```
public static WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", TestUtil.CHROMEDRIVER_PATH);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
System.out.println("URL Is "+prop.getProperty("url"));
driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(TestUtil.SET_SCRIPT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
return driver;
```

**Chrome Version is - 108.0.5359.95 **
Chrome Driver version is 108.0.5359.71

Answer (score 0):

can you use

```
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage")
```

instead of

```
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox")
```